# Htaccess rewrite in subfolder with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite `/streams/post.php?id=1` into `/streams/thread/1` .

I did find some codes for .htaccess with parameters but it didn't work in the subfolder.

**Also**, should I put another .htaccess in the subfolder or use the one on the main directory? ( `/.htaccess` or `/streams/.htaccess`)

Also, in the past when I've rewritten, sometimes it redirects from for example `/streams/thread/1` to `/streams/post.php?id=` and sometimes it actually displays `/streams/thread/1` in the URL, I would like it to display `/streams/thread/1` in the URL, not just redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your htaccess in root or `streams` folder (that's up to you).

**In root folder**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/streams/post\.php\?id=([0-9]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . streams/thread/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^streams/thread/([0-9]+)$ streams/post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

**In streams folder**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /streams/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/streams/post\.php\?id=([0-9]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . thread/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^thread/([0-9]+)$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Say I want to do this on several boards (streams is one board), would I simply copy everything below RewriteBase (doing this in root) and change "streams" to whatever the other boards is named?

Comment: Yes if your other board is the same case